# Base64 analogs for transfer image from server

Tags: java, image, gwt, base64, encoder

I need to reduce data amount that is sending from server to client. I have an image that dynamically changing every 5 seconds. Than this image is encoding by **Base64**, method `encodeBase64String(byte[] image)` and in such  condition is passing to client, where `img.setUrl("data:image/png;base64,"+encodedImage64.toString());` method shows this image on browser.

**The next question is :**
I have to reduce amount of transferring data. With base64 image in String condition is very heavy, do somebody knows another encoders, or techniques that can reduce weight of image. Or may be some alternative solutions?

Comment: Couldn't you just upload the image ?

Comment: i need it to be passed into the model in accordance to architecture of application